# Converting init into date?

Tags: r

I have been working with a dataset that comes with a date column. When I run typeof(headlineDat$Date) I get a type integer. [image: This is what my data frame looks like]

I've tried pasting in a few things I found off google but none have seemed to work. I've tried running this piece of code

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(headlineDat$Time.read,format= "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

My aim is to have the same format as the year column below. The reason why I want to do this is that I want to be able to create a unique identifier so I can easily match dates when I merge the two data frames.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated !
This is my dput output:

```
dput(droplevels(headlineDat[1:5, ]))
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("2018-04-26T11:31:02+00:00", 
"2018-05-02T21:10:20+00:00", "2018-05-03T15:30:59+00:00", "2018-05-03T18:00:39+00:00"
), class = "factor"), Headline = structure(c(5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("Bitcoin Futures Trading Questioned By Chinese National Media", 
"Daily Volatility Decline? Bitcoin Has Seen $1K Range 43 Times In 2018", 
"Reddit to Relaunch Bitcoin Payments (And Add More Cryptos)", 
"Sell In May and Go Away? Not for Bitcoin Bulls", "Square Books Small Profit for First Quarter of Bitcoin Sales"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: What I want my dates to look like]

Comment: Dates are stored internally as numbers. Use `class(headlineDate$Date)` to get a better idea of what's there.

Comment: Also, no one can test code on data in an image. If you want people to help, post data in a copy/pasteable format. `dput` is best for this, `dput(droplevels(headlineDate[1:5, ]))` would be great. Just edit the result of that into your question.

Comment: I ran the `class(headlineDate$Date)` and it returns a factor. I have updated my question with the dput result. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with a standard format, so `as.Date` does the conversion just fine.

```
headlineDat$Date = as.Date(headlineDat$Date)
```